# Process not defined at _Environment.initClass (environment.js:5:30) at ../node_modules/braintree/lib/braintree/environment.js (environment.js:78:13)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, braintree

I am not able to figure out what happened randomnly
IS this frontend or backend error?

```
   environment.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at _Environment.initClass (environment.js:5:30)
    at node_modules/braintree/lib/braintree/environment.js (environment.js:78:13)
    at __require2 (chunk-3EJPJMEH.js?v=cde9a648:15:50)
    at node_modules/braintree/lib/braintree.js (braintree.js:4:19)
    at __require2 (chunk-3EJPJMEH.js?v=cde9a648:15:50)
    at node_modules/braintree/index.js (index.js:3:18)
    at __require2 (chunk-3EJPJMEH.js?v=cde9a648:15:50)
    at index.js:3:18
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.